# XSLT - XPath, deepest element of certain type

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to find out a way that ensure that the element of interest does not (recursively) contain a "identical" element. E.g.:

```
<Ev>
   <Ev attr="0">
      <Ev someOtherAttr="str1">
         <Ev attr="1">
            <Ev>
            </Ev>
         </Ev>
      </Ev>
   </Ev>
</Ev>
```

Here, I would like to make sure that the element I have is the deepest one with attribute named attr (The attribute value is could be arbitrary and should not be matched nor taken into consideration).

So, in this case I would like to select `<Ev attr="1">` out of the two "indentical" elements:

`<Ev attr="0">` and `<Ev atttr="1">`

**What I've been aiming at:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Ev/@attr">
    <xsl:if select="//*[not(child::Ev/@attr)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::node())"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But the **if** part is not good of course, perhaps a for-each `select="<condition_a> and not(<condition_b>)"` would be the way to go?

**(Edited the question with what I've tried)**

Best Regards,
Mr. Pistol

Comment: Have you tried anything on your end @Pete? if yes then you need to post what you have tried. If no then, you should try something yourself and post ! Because "here is the requirement, give code for me" type of questions are not encouraged and usually treated as homework stuff and get many downvotes and close votes..

Comment: Please show us the XSLT you have so far and where this would fit into that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. But I will in the future :-). Now I've added my thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath expression should work although it's not very efficient:

```
//Ev[@attr and not(.//Ev[@attr])]
```

Comment: I've will try it out ASAP (meeting).

Comment: Thanks, It suites my needs perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this suit your needs?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Ev[@attr]" mode="deepest">
      <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::*)" data-type="number" order="descending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Ev" mode="deepest">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <!-- If we get to the inside of this xsl:if, the context node is 
           the deepest Ev in the selection -->
       <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::node())"/>          
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample XML, this produces:

```
4
```

Comment: No! Actually he wants it to be generalized .. say if there is one more element with name `Ev` having `@someOtherAttr` appears under `Ev` having `@someOtherAttr` then the child should be ignored.. or probably if it has one more attribute `@attr` then should be retained!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I go for nwellnhofs solution.